# What is the error that causes figma.mixed to not be accepted in angular16

Tags: css, angular, figma

I am using angular to create a web app but I keep having this error in every of my CSS code
I was using figma.mixed but it keeps wanting me to insert an ) after figma

```
template-new-details-tab {
 gap: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: flex;
 overflow: hidden;
 align-self: stretch;
 align-items: flex-start;
 padding-top: 0.8rem;
 border-color: #dddddd;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: Symbol(figma.mixed)px;
 padding-left: 1.2rem;
 padding-right: 1.2rem;
 padding-bottom: 0.8rem;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 border-top-width: 0px;
 border-left-width: 0px;
 border-right-width: 0px;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
```